# JSON.parse not working correctly as needed

Tags: mysql, json

im working with SQL and its JSON data type, ive inserted a Array Object and Appending new objects, but when i use

```js
"UPDATE introductions SET all_replies = COALESCE(JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(roles, '$', '"
  + JSON.stringify(appendedData)
  + "'), JSON_ARRAY(null)) WHERE id2 = 1;"
```

and then when i go on node to parse the data it doesnt work.
heres a picture of the inserted data and at the bottom is the appended data

[image: ignore the dummy text]

but you can see at the bottom "id-4" is different, when printing this to my terminal ive tried parsing it already

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(results[0].all_replies))
```

infact, ive tried multiple things

```js
console.log(eval(JSON.parse(result[0].all_replies)))
console.log(eval(result[0].all_replies))
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0].all_replies)))
```

so basically, whenever i append a new object it doesnt let me parse it as if it was inserted.
sorry for my poor explanation in advance..

```js
var theJSON = [
  { "id": 1,
    "info": {
      "username": "amazon",
      "message": "jeff bezox.",
      "likes": 222,
      "time_created": ers
    } 
  },
  { "id": 2, 
    "info": {
      "username": "facebook",
      "message": "ik you bod",
      "likes": 92,
      "time_created": ers
    } 
  },
  { "id": 3,
    "info": {
      "username": "fortnite",
      "message": "kids love me lol",
      "likes": 12,
      "time_created": ers
    } 
  }]

var appenedData =   { "id": 1,
    "info": {
      "username": "amazon",
      "message": "jeff bezox.",
      "likes": 222,
      "time_created": ers
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code, data, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: I've posted code and data, there isnt any real 'errors' its just not doing what i need it todo or my code is not correct.

Comment: @vector17 It is hard to test your script without the data in text format. We will not bother trying by typing it ourselves. For example what is `all_replies` - it is not in the JavaScript you posted. Also why eval?

Comment: @vector17 - Please re-read my comment above: "Post ...data... **as text**, not as a *picture* of text."

Comment: Ive added the data, sorry. i Misunderstood what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as MySQL is concerned, you are appending a string to your JSON array.

To have it interpret the JSON as JSON, you need to cast it.

For example

```js
let query = `UPDATE introductions
  SET all_replies = COALESCE(
    JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(roles, '$', CAST('${JSON.stringify(appendedData)}' AS JSON)),
    JSON_ARRAY(null)
  ) WHERE id2 = 1`
```

Demo ~ https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xnTrecnFBgiQWwuvTaAYu4/0

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-converting-between-types

FYI, I knew absolutely nothing on this topic before answering and found everything I needed in the MySQL manual. It's a fantastic resource and well worth reading.

Comment: There's some syntax error in your query and i cant seem to find where.

Comment: What exactly does the error say? Add `console.log(query)` to see what it actually looks like. Finally, make sure you're using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and not a regular string

Comment: let query = `UPDATE introductions SET all_replies = COALESCE(JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(all_replies, '$', CAST('${JSON.stringify(appendedData)}') AS JSON), JSON_ARRAY(null)) WHERE id2 = 1`

Comment: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS JSON), JSON_ARRAY(null)) WHERE id2 = 1' at line 1

Comment: oh sorry, one second.

Comment: UPDATE introductions SET all_replies = COALESCE(JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(all_replies, '$', CAST('{"id":21,"info":{"username":"snapchat","message":"jeff bezox.","likes":23222,"time_created":"2019-12-11T23:40:43.378Z"}}') AS JSON), JSON_ARRAY(null)) WHERE id2 = 1

Comment: that is the output of ```console.log(query)```

Comment: Ah sorry, the `AS JSON` is meant to be within the `CAST` parentheses. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much, been waiting on an answer all day.